# HP Server Proliant ML110 G7, with 2GB base memory need to add another 4GB memory

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

having problems adding a new 4GB DIMM. 
On server memory#1 2GB 2rX8 PC3-10600E 9-11 ECC DIMM
new memory #2 4GB PC3-10600 Reg Cl9 240 ECC - pin DIMM
Im following the memory secuence by placing the #1 memory on slot 2A and memory #2 on slot 4B.
On first screen on BIoS recognizes 2 GB, but inside BiOS (F9) recognizes 6GB. When proceeding to Windows Server 2008 R1, it still shows 2GB. 
I've have try all posible changes, switching slot location 2GBx4GB 4GB (beeping) 2Gb and 4GBx2GB, but still can meke it work.

Does anyone knows how to make it work?
Be happy to get some help.

Regards

Comment: Seems like contacting the vendor would be the appropriate step here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the [HP Memory Configurator](http://www.hp.com/go/ddr3memory-configurator), and then consider applying the latest firmware, Etc.